# How do I get the contents of the response body of a GET request before the POST request fires? Can this be done with promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm receiving a JSON object from the front-end and sending it to my backend to the endpoint /getData. Here, I use a GET request to obtain data from an API and I need to send both the JSON object and the GET response body in the final POST request. But when I send the request, the body of the GET response comes in too late and "formInfo" is undefined.

How do I fix this so the POST request sends once the GET is fulfilled?

```
 app.post('/getData', function(req, res) {
    debugger;
    var data = req.body;
    console.log(data);
    toSend = data;
    res.send({msg: "Success"});
    var findID = {};
    var endPoint = 'https://secure.p01.eloqua.com/API/REST/2.0/assets/form/' + toSend["formID"].toString();
    var options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {'Authorization': authenticationHeader, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    };
    request.get(endPoint, options, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
        findID = body["elements"];
            request({
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {'content-type': 'application/json', 'authorization': authenticationHeader},
                    url: 'http://localhost:3000/handleData',
                    json: {
                        "tuples": toSend,
                        "formInfo": body['elements']
                    }},
                function (error, response, body) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)?

It's [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch) in modern browsers - and you can transpile it worst case - and NodeJS.

With it you'd be able to chain requests, e.g.

```
fetch(`first.url.com`)
  .then(response => 
    fetch(`second.url.com`, {body: response.body})
  )
```